# Multiple domains, one email account?

Tags: email, exchange-server

I am wondering if something like this is possible and if so, how to go about configuring and setting this up?

I have an Exchange Server 2007.
I have a domain name: abc.com for example

Emails can be sent to and from this domain. Great.

I now have another domain, def.com.
I have set the mx records to point to the IP address of abc.com.
I also configured exchange user accounts to accept the def.com domain so any emails sent to it, are picked up - that works fine. Great. But the email address sent to happens to be translated to the abc.com domain rather than the actual domain it was sent to (def.com)

so now, I want to know if it is possible to do the following:

- when an email gets sent TO, say, info@def.com, I want the reply to come FROM def.com
- when an email gets sent TO abc.com, I want the reply to come from that domain as it currently does.

any ideas? is this possible?

I am also using OWA for sending/receiving emails. I could probably use outlook if needs be to get it to work.

thanks!

Comment: With standard exchange/outlook features this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

With standard exchange/outlook features this is not possible.
Simplest way to do it is to create a second account for info@def.com and then give the user info@abc.com access to the second one.

In recent outlook versions this works just fine.

Comment: when you say in recent outlook versions... do you mean exchange version? which version?

Comment: No, I did mean Outlook version. With OL2003 there is no easy way to have multiple exchange accounts and use the correct sender address and using the proper "Sent items" etc. With every new Outlook version this has been improved step by step. With OL2013 you can have multiple exchange accounts and using the per-account sent-items, drafts etc. For OWA you can do the same with Exchange 2007(sp1?), but you will have multiple browser windows open...

Comment: I have outlook 2010 and outlook 2013 and I know I can setup multiple profiles and that's fine. But from an OWA perspective on Exchange 2007 SP1, is it possible to have an email coming in from a domain and responding as if from THAT domain?. Currently, this does not happen but only sends from the original/default domain on the user account. My user account has email addresses configured for 2 domains, one of it being the default obviously. I don't want to change the default.

Comment: No, this is not possible. You will have to setup two accounts in exchange and then user has then to select the collect account in OWA. No way to have it done automagically

Comment: Thanks. Hmm. It would be good if there was a way. In Outlook, is there a way to do this? For example, if I have 2 email accounts, one from each domain, is there a way to select which account to send from rather than opening multiple instances of outlook?

Comment: Yes, you have multiple accounts on the left side in outlook and depending in which you reply (or start writing new mails) the correct address will be used.

Comment: how do I configure this?

Comment: There is nothing to configure. Just create one account per email address, give the user access to them in exchange and add the accounts to the users outlook.